# two keys map in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I plan to use a map with two keys for my assignment. And I create my map like following:

```
map<pair<string, string>, int> myMap;
map<pair<string, string>, int>:: iterator it;
```

I had a hard time on how to use map.find() and map.insert() for finding existing entry in the map or insert a new value if two keys combination is new. Can some one give an example?

Comment: You pass to `find` an appropriate `pair`, for example `map.find(make_pair("foo", "bar"))`. There's nothing special about it.

Comment: @DanielFrey seems to work on ideone: http://ideone.com/yHxxN5

Comment: That is quick!! thanks, how about map.insert(), in one key map, i can do map.insert(pair<string, int>("foo", 10)), not sure about two keys.

Comment: I was so stupid. I actually tried make_pair, just keep using <> after ti, instead of ()..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be the same as with any map, except you have to make pairs for your key.

Insert :

```
map< pair<string,string>, int > mymap; 

pair<string, string> key = make_pair("bob", "sue");
mymap[ key ] = 5; // you can inline make_pair if you prefer.

// or you can use insert method
mymap.insert( key, 5 );
```

Find :

```
pair<string, string> key = make_pair("bob", "sue"); 
auto it = mymap.find( key ); // you can inline make_pair if you prefer.
if ( it != mymap.end() )
{
  cout << it->second;
}
```

Note that using strings as a key in a map can have performance issues. Also, the order of the strings in the pair has significance.

Answer (score 1):

```
it = myMap.find(make_pair("hi","mike"));
```

`insert` is a little awkward because you're inserting a pair whose first component is also a pair:

```
myMap.insert(make_pair( make_pair("hi","john"), 4 ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [Boost multiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/index.html)

Comment: That doesn't seem related to `pair`-keys.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
typedef pair<string, string> key_type;
map<key_type, int> myMap;
myMap.insert(std::make_pair(key_type("a","b"),1));
map<pair<string, string>, int>::iterator it;
it = myMap.find(key_type("a","b"));
```

`insert` can be replaced with `emplace` in C++11 to shorten the code:

```
myMap.emplace(key_type("a","b"),1);
```